# How to highlight all children views inside a Layout only when the Layout is pressed?

Tags: android

I'm trying to highlight all content of a LinearLayout only when the user is pressing it.
There is someway to do this?

Comment: do you want to change just **LinearLayout** background or backgrounds of all children?

Comment: @Alexander I want to change the style of the text in all textviews, the backgrounds of the layout and all it childrens and all imageviews source image

Answer (score 0):

You can always get all the children of the LinearLayout and iterate to each one of them and then do the highlighting for each child view.

```
int childcount = your_linear_layout.getChildCount();
for (int i=0; i < childcount; i++){
      View v = your_linear_layout.getChildAt(i);
      //do you fancy stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Android way of doing this is to reference an xml selector for each view. I will demonstrate this for a simple `TextView`:

R.layout.textview_layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_textview_background"
        android:textColor="@color/selector_textview_textcolor"/>
        <!--The latter selector for the textcolor is not included below-->
        <!--Just go ahead and write one yourself and put it in R.color-->
</RelativeLayout>
```

R.drawable.selector_textview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tv_background_active" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tv_background_active" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tv_background_idle"/>
</selector>
```

R.drawable.tv_background_active.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
        android:color="@color/highlighingcolor"/>
</shape>
```

R.drawable.tv_background_idle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
        android:color="@color/regularcolor"/>
</shape>
```